# Display AD contact information in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Is there a way to link the Active Directory to a SharePoint list and pull metadata from AD into the SharePoint list?

E.g:
Pull name, role, Location from AD and store it in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually makes more sense to pull that information into SharePoint's user profile service than to push it into a SharePoint list.

However, the answer is yes. Here are two options:

**Exposing Active Directory through an External Content Type**

SharePoint 2010 introduced the concept of **External Content Types** (and External Lists that use those content types). An External Content Type pulls its information from a data source external to SharePoint instead of storing its data in a traditional SharePoint list, but it can be displayed within SharePoint in a manner consistent with SharePoint lists and libraries.

When you add an External Content type through SharePoint 2010, you can choose between three types of data sources: **WCF Service** (for web services), **SQL Server** (for a Microsoft SQL Server database), and **.NET Type** (for a .NET assembly connector or a custom .NET connector). Depending on your relative comfort level with SQL Server and .NET programming, you can either set up a SQL query view that looks at Active Directory or use C# to write a .NET connector that connects to Active Directory.

For more information on writing a .NET connector, refer to Microsoft's Documentation: [Differences Between Using the .NET Assembly Connector and Writing a Custom Connector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554911(v=office.14).aspx).

In SharePoint 2013 you can also [create an external content type from any oData source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163967.aspx). Again, this may entail writing your own wrapper code to expose Active Directory in a way that SharePoint can consume.

**Pushing Active Directory Data into a SharePoint List**

An external content type resembles a SharePoint list but the data is stored externally. That means, for example, that you can't set up SharePoint alerts and workflows on the records. If you truly need to push the data from Active Directory into a SharePoint list, you'll need to explore other options.

One such option is to have a piece of code run on a scheduled basis to continually update a SharePoint list with information from Active Directory. This could take any of the following forms:

- A custom SharePoint timer job written in .NET
- A custom Powershell script (or console application) located on one of your SharePoint web front end servers that can be run as a Windows Scheduled Task
- A site workflow with an action to query Active Directory and use the resulting information to populate a list

The challenge in every case will be programmatically updating existing records in the SharePoint list, unless you take the easy way out and just delete and re-create each record every time the process runs.